Query has been cancelled because the estimated cost of this query exceeds the configured threshold
Whenever I run this query:
SELECT trade_detail_id,trade_side_id,id,is_last,is_xml_detail_filled,save_date_time,trade_id,trade_ligne_id,type,xml_detailled_info,xml_state 
FROM some_table 
WHERE (NOT (is_xml_detail_filled =1))

SQL Server sends back this error:

Msg 8649, Level 17, State 1, Line 12
The query has been canceled because the estimated cost of this query (1191) exceeds the configured threshold of 12. Contact the system administrator.

In sp_configure, the query governor cost limit is set to 0.
In Server Properties -> connections, "Use query governor to prevent long running queries" is disabled.
DBCC USEROPTIONS doesn't mention anything

So why the error?
If I use SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT then the error goes away, but I shouldn't have to use that command here if there are no server wide limits.
SQL Server 2019 CU28 instance on Windows 2019.

This doesn't involve the resource governor, user options, or long-running queries; it's a system configuration based on estimated costs (though there is a SET command to achieve this for the current session, I suspect this isn't where it's coming from, and it wouldn't show up in DBCC USEROPTIONS anyway). Check:
SELECT value, value_in_use 
  FROM sys.configurations
 WHERE name = N'query governor cost limit';

My guess is value_in_use will return 12 (even if value shows 0, which could mean someone corrected the value but didn't run RECONFIGURE). To change it, you can set it to either 0 (no limit) or something > 1191 so at least this specific query can run. For example:
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'query governor cost limit', 0;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;

If that isn't the issue, it might have been set in SSMS > Tools > Options > Query Execution > SQL Server > Advanced > SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT, which will override the server setting:



This defaults to 0, but if you've overridden it to test something, it will be true for all of your sessions. If you can't change the setting or currently don't have access to the machine where you were getting this error, try running the same query from any other workstation, on the server itself, or from another application altogether (C#, PowerShell, etc).

That was it Aaron, not sure how that value of 12 got there but I haven't found that value in my other SSMS 20.1s. Thank you again for resolving that
